# Text underneath text in same table cell

Tags: tables

In my table, i want the "2" to go right under the "1" in the same cell, how do I do that?

here is my code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} | p{1,5cm} | p{1,5cm} | p{1,5 cm} | p{8,3cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Uge} & \textbf{Speciel dato} & \textbf{ugedag} & \textbf{Antal blokke} & \textbf{Aktivitet} \\ \hline \hline
12 & 17/3 & Tirsdag Torsdag & 1 2 & Text \\ \hline
13 & 9C & 19C & Text & Text \\ \hline
14 & 10C & 21C & Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

\end{center}

Comment: In a new cell with an empty rest of the row? Or just like a fraction? Or perhaps something else.

Comment: If you don't need paragraph style wrapping between lines of your stacked text, the `stackengine` package offers many options to address this, with various justification options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `array`, `makecell` and `cellspace` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | S{p{1cm}} | *{3}{ >{\centering}S{p{1,5cm}} |} S{m{8,3cm}} |}
\hline
\thead{Uge} & \thead{Speciel \\ dato} & \thead{ugedag} & \thead{Antal\\ blokke} & \thead{Aktivitet} \\
\hline \hline
12 & 17/3 & \makecell{Tirsdag\\ Torsdag} & \makecell{1\\ 2}  & Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
\hline
13 & 9C & 19C & Text & Text \\
\hline
14 & 10C & 21C & Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

you have this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to achieve the desired output. One way involves placing `Torsdag` and `2` in their own separate row. Doing so may be a good idea not only because it'll create the desired output, but also because the result will be robust to a widening of the third column, which might result in "Tirsdag" and "Torsdag" (Tuesday and Thursday??) suddenly appearing on the same line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | p{1cm} | p{1,5cm} | p{1,5cm} | p{1,5 cm} | X |}
\hline
\textbf{Uge} & \textbf{Speciel dato} & \textbf{ugedag} & \textbf{Antal blokke} & \textbf{Aktivitet} \\ 
\hline \hline
12 & 17/3 & Tirsdag  & 1 & Text \\ 
& & Torsdag & 2 & \\
\hline
13 & 9C & 19C & Text & Text \\ 
\hline
14 & 10C & 21C & Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If 1 and 2 shouldn't be centered, `\newline` does the work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} | p{1,5cm} | p{1,5cm} | p{1,5 cm} | p{8,3cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Uge} & \textbf{Speciel dato} & \textbf{ugedag} & \textbf{Antal blokke} & \textbf{Aktivitet} \\ \hline \hline
12 & 17/3 & Tirsdag Torsdag & 1\newline 2 & Text \\ \hline
13 & 9C & 19C & Text & Text \\ \hline
14 & 10C & 21C & Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]